# Trying to have a view reflect an editor's status

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have a view that I want to react to what happens in the editor. Right now I have a button that I want it so that when clicked it updates the data in the view to some new set of information. Where do I start, I have my selection event but no idea on how to communicate between the two. I'm looking for a loose coupling solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways of doing this, but I've used the JFace [IPropertyChangeListener](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Futil%2FIPropertyChangeListener.html) interface in the past for simple event propagation.

Make your view implement IPropertyChangeListener. Create a Singleton class that you can register your `IPropertyChangeListener` with, and send a [PropertyChangeEvent](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Futil%2FPropertyChangeEvent.html) to. Then in the constructor of your view, register it with your Singleton.

Now you can get hold of your Singleton in your editor and fire off an event that will get picked up in your view.

Example code for the Singleton:

```
public class PropertyChangeEventBus {

    private static PropertyChangeEventBus s_instance = new PropertyChangeEventBus();

    public static PropertyChangeEventBus instance()
    {
        return s_instance;
    }

    private Set<IPropertyChangeListener> m_listeners;

    private PropertyChangeEventBus()
    {
        // use CopyOnWriteArraySet to prevent ConcurrentModificationExceptions
        m_listeners = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<IPropertyChangeListener>();
    }

    public void addListener(IPropertyChangeListener listener)
    {   
        m_listeners.add(listener);       
    }

    public void removeListener(IPropertyChangeListener listener)
    {
        m_listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void fire(final PropertyChangeEvent event)
    {   
        // run property change events in UI thread to prevent having to have lots of syncExecs in the listener methods
        ViewUtils.syncExec(new Runnable()
        {           
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for (IPropertyChangeListener listener : m_listeners) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        listener.propertyChange(event);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {                       
                        //log it, present error message
                    }
                }
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

Example Code for the View:

```
//The constructor
public MyView() 
{
    PropertyChangeEventBus.instance().addListener(this);
}

@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
{
    if(event.getProperty().equals(SOME_CONSTANT))
    {           
        // Refresh View         
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to give some sort of feedback on my answer? I spent some time on this and it will provide you with what you require.